# cursor to listview android 2.2+

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

It's been hours that I am trying to create a listview from a cursor and it's just not working it's really upseting me!! I have a cursor filled with the needed data and I need to take these data and add them to my listview I created an activity that extends from a listactivity and I placed the following code inside of it:

```
ListView listv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        Cursor cu;              
        cu=myDbHelper.GetCursor();   

        ListAdapter adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rating,cu,new String[]{"Title"}, new int[]{R.id.listText},flag_that_I_dont_know_how_to_use);   
        listv.setAdapter(adapter);
        myDbHelper.close();
        cu.close();
```

I don't know how to use the flag and the other constructor of the simplecursoradapter is deprecated and I have two layouts one is the rating layout containing a single textview and one layout containing the listview... and I am not getting what I want I'm getting either an empty page either an error depending on the used flag... please help!!

**Edit1:**

I replaced the listview1 with andriod:id/list and I wrote in my code:

```
Cursor cu;              
        cu=myDbHelper.GetCursor();   
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rating,cu,new String[]{"Title"}, new int[]{R.id.listText},CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);   
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and that got me an empty page;

**Edit**
Does anyone have any idea? or does anyone have any sample that I can look at and see why my list view is not working..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the edit1 worked the flag is:
CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER
and I just needed to remove the cu.close(); as when I was closing the cursor I was having a white page because the page is taking its content from the cursor and when it's closed there is no more content to that page!!
and I removed the extend listview no need for that I added extends activity...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ListView listv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
                Cursor cu;              
                cu=myDbHelper.GetCursor();   
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rating,cu,new String[]{"Title"}, new int[]{R.id.listText},0);   
                listv.setAdapter(adapter);
                myDbHelper.close();
                cu.close();
```

Comment: hey thanks but I already done that and I got:java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'           although when I used a list predefined from android I got an empty page...